# Deploy Multiple Next js application on azure app service using virtual application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, next.js13

I am trying to host 2 next js application on azure app service with following virtual application defined.

[Virtual application path mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qDCV.png)

mysite.azure.net/  will have my container next app.
mysite.azure.net/auth will have my another next app.

I have followed all things to deploy next js app on azure app service.

here is my server.js

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === "/a") {
      app.render(req, res, "/a", query);
    } else if (pathname === "/b") {
      app.render(req, res, "/b", query);
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:", port);
  });
});
```

here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:
     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

package.json has startup command `node server.js`.

Both App has same server.js and web.config.

My base application works without problem.

But navigating to /auth always shows 404 not found.

Should I make any changes in root web.config for handling *auth* requests ?

If anyone successfully hosted multiple next js application on Azure app service, please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue. I was missing assetPrefix and basePath in next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  assetPrefix: '/summary/',
  basePath: '/summary',
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
```

Sub domain application should always have this configured otherwise, sub (virtual) applications will always show 404 Not found.

Answer (score 0):

I Followed these steps to run the  web app  in local and Azure .

- I have  added   `auth` file   to  the `server.js`  in the `page` folder
- Sample code with a function called `handleAuthRequest` that takes `req` (request) and `res` (response) as parameters, presumably to handle an authentication request.

```js
// authResponse.js
const handleAuthRequest = (req, res) => {
  // Your authentication logic goes here
  // For example, you might check if the user is authenticated

  // Sending a response
  res.send('Authentication is done!');
};

module.exports = handleAuthRequest;
```

```js
<!-- web.config -->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="nodejs">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Project Structure:**

```
├── pages
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── a.js
│   ├── b.js
│   └── auth
│       └── index.js
├── server.js
├── web.config
├── package.json
└── ...
```

**Local:**
[image]

[image]

- I followed the  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode#configure-the-app-service-app-and-deploy-code)  for the Deploy from VSCode.

**Deployment status:**
[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: thing is we have separate micro frontend app that handles authentication and i have to deploy it on /auth.

Comment: Make sure to add the parameters of the  authentication in the configuration of the web app authentication